# Installing pillow on windows fails to find libjpeg

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, python-imaging-library

Sys: Windows 7 Prof;
Python v3.3

I've tried to use:

- 'easy_install Pillow'
- 'pip install use-wheel Pillow'
- Download package manually and 'python setup.py install'

but all the time i cant install any extensions:

```
*** TKINTER support not available
(Tcl/Tk 8.5 libraries needed)
*** JPEG not support available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
```

I've manually installed libjpeg but still the results were the same. I've alsot tried to change JPEG_ROOT path to point it somehow to the correct dll but it did not work too.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try python extension packages for windows：
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

There are 32- and 64-bit Windows binaries you can simply install

Comment: It worked! Thanks. But still no idea why with pip/easy_install it wasnt working. Maybe someone can tell me?

Comment: Well i was trying to install Pillow on 18.12.2013 or 17.12.2013 so it might be the reason why it was not working. Thanks for reply :), If i have some spare time i will uninstall my current package and try again with easy_install or pip.

Comment: this link no longer works