# How to install Pillow dependencies on Windows (without binaries)?

Tags: windows, zlib, django-cms, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I'm trying to run django-cms on Windows 10 with Python3 in a virtualenv.

If I'm following the installation steps on their website and running the command `djangocms mysite` then I get this error:

```
Creating the project
Please wait while I install dependencies
Dependencies installed
Creating the project

*****************************************************************

Check documentation at https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io

*****************************************************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\guter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", 
line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\guter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", 
line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\guter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\Scripts\djangocms.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\users\guter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\djangocms_installer\main.py", line 36, in
execute
install.check_install(config_data)
File "c:\users\guter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\djangocms_installer\install\__init__.py",
line 79, in check_install
raise EnvironmentError('\n'.join(errors))

OSError: Pillow is not installed check for installation errors and see 
"Libraries installation issues" documentation section:
https://djangocms-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html
```

It seems like **libjpeg** (for JPEG support in Pillow) and **zlib** (for PNG support in Pillow) is missing for the Installation of PIL, but is there an "easy" way on windows to get them? Disableing is not the solution, because they are for django-cms required...

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672530/installing-pillow-on-windows-fails-to-find-libjpeg) solution will work, but for an virtualenv, its not a pretty workaround...

But the problem should be solveable? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're linking to an old version of the docs. The latest version https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.1/installation.html says:

> In
>   general, we aim to support all current versions of Linux, macOS, and
>   Windows.

But:

> We don’t recommend trying to build on Windows. It is a maze of
>   twisty passages, mostly dead ends. There are build scripts and notes
>   for the Windows build in the w i n b u i l d directory.

However:

> We provide Pillow binaries for Windows compiled for the matrix of
>   supported Pythons in both 32 and 64-bit versions in wheel, egg, and
>   executable installers. These binaries have all of the optional libraries
>   included

So I suggest you install with pip in the usual way.

Comment: Even the simple pip install does not wor. It does not compile _imagingft

Comment: @DennyWeinberg What version of Python and Windows are you using? `pip install pillow` should install a binary wheel that doesn't need compiling. Otherwise, download the appropriate wheel file from here and try `pip install some_name.whl`

Comment: We need to use 3.4.2 because the latest one isn't compatible with embedded py distros. Isn't this version a whl?
When I use "-m pip install pillow==3.4.2", it says that "zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using", so we use "--install-option="--disable-zlib"". But then he disables the whl feature... Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You should try to install Pillow through easy_install:

```
easy_install Pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it solved the problem, pillow worked fine, i don't know what happens for you as I'm using this for Django server purposes.

```
easy_install Pillow
```

This worked on Windows 10 64-bit